# Automatic Creation of branch From JIRA

Tags: branch, jira

Presently, the workflow to manage our code is erroneous. To over come this we have decided upon the new workflow. Now with tool in hands we trying to implement this.

The first step towards implementing is to figure out the way to automatic create feature branch from develop when ever the item moves from TO-DO ---> In-Progress in JIRA.

I spent yesterday and today to figure this out but with no result. As per Atlassian documentation there is a way to create triggers that will automatically update item in JIRA whenever some action is performed against the item key. However, I need the other way round as in where if an item is moved from to-do --> in -progress a branch is created. Following is what I  would like to achieve.

TO D0 --> In Progress -- branch forked out from Develop.
In Progress --> Need Testing -- forked out branch merged into testing enviroment.

In Testing --> Testing Done --- Merge the forked branch to develop as well as staging and delete the fork branch.

Please suggest.

Comment: What version control system are you using? If it's git, do you use Atlassian's Bitbucket (formerly Stash) as well?

Comment: Hi Simbabuqe, we are using BitBucket.

Answer (score 0):

We have all parts of our dev, QA, and release workflow integrated into JIRA in some way, but not all of them are strictly automated. I would not recommend your approach. Before Stash (now called Bitbucket) had the feature, we wrote a custom Google estension to inject a section onto the ticket detail to present branch creation links which linked to Stash's branch create screen. We simply required each developer to create their branches using this method in order to make sure all branches were of the exact issue ID (JIRA-123). The extension then also looked up the appropriate branch by issue ID and would display it on the ticket detail screen if there was one.

If you are trying to do all of this without Stash, you certainly can have git  automatically create a branch, but my guess is you will have to start cleaning up branches quite often if certain tickets start but then get changed or deprioritized later.

At any rate, if you really want to do this, you need to go to http://(yourjira)/plugins/servlet/webhooks  or hit GG from any JIRA screen and type "webhooks"

You can create a hook, check the Issue updated box so it only fires when the issue is transitioned, and point your webhook to a URL for the script you'll write to create the branch.

In PHP you can use this code to receive the webhook POST data, and set $transition to the value of the new status when the ticket is moved, in your case "In-Progress" I guess.

```
$raw = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($raw);

if (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE && $data)
{
    // get the transition name if it exists and this is an update command
    $changelog_items_array = $data->changelog->items;
    $changelog_last_item_key = array_search(max($changelog_items_array),$changelog_items_array);
    $transition = $changelog_items_array[$changelog_last_item_key]->toString;
}
```

Comment: To add to this, if you do have Bitbucket already, and you have linked your two applications using GG "application links" then you should be able to see the Bitbucket tools on the right side of your ticket detail screen. Then you can just have users manually create their branches from there in two clicks.